# Windows 7 batch files: How to write string to text file without carriage return AND trailing space?

Tags: windows-7, batch-file, ms-dos

I am trying to have my batch file write a string of text to a text file.  At first, the command I was using was writing an extra carriage return to the end of the string, but I found this command that prevented that:

`echo|set /p=hello>hello.txt`

However, now it's putting a trailing space at the end.  I need *only the string I specify* to be written without any extra characters.  Is this possible?

Comment: Doesn't `echo mystring>test.txt` do just that?

Comment: That's how I was doing it before when it was adding a carriage return at the end.

Comment: Odd; I just tested it myself.  When I open it in vim, the output contains no line breaks or spaces after the string.

Comment: I just tested it in a command window and the carriage return is there when I open it in Notepad.

Comment: I am 100% wrong on this.  Sorry.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This command should work exactly like you want - write only "hello", without any extra symbols.

```
> echo|set /P ="hello" > foo

> dir foo
...
09.07.2012  19:25                 5 foo
               1 File(s)              5 bytes
```

Looks like exactly 5 symbols without CR+LF to me.

Comment: Oleg is right.  The SET /P is designed to output a question and accept input from the user on the same line, so it automatically excludes line breaks.  The `wc` command actually counts LF characters, so it should show 0 if the line feed is actually omitted.  In Oleg's example that is true.

Comment: very good!  Worked awesomely!

Comment: I'm not sure *why* that should work, however I found it doesn't work for spaces.  Anyone got an idea how I can pad on the left?